# Webex on Mac: select display for fullscreen view

Tags: multiple-monitors, fullscreen, webex, cisco-webex

I am using Webex Meetings on Mac with three displays. I have the Webex app running on my main display. I see other person shared screen. I want to see it full screen, so I double click it. It opens on some other, secondary display. How do I make it show on my main display? It's quite annoying.
Thanks :)

Comment: idk Webex, so this is generic. 1) double-clicking a title bar does not make fullscreen, it makes maximised - the two are different. 2) how are your displays laid out - are they one Space shared, or many Spaces, one per display? 3) Do you have Webex assigned affinity to any particular Space? [right click icon in Dock > Options]. 4) If assigned to a specific Space, set to None & try again. Since Mojave, some apps cannot open a new window on anything other than "display1" of a single Space with multiple displays [bug].

Comment: Hello Tetsujin, thanks for your reply. 
1) yeah, I know that,
2) I've unticked the "Displays have separate Spaces" in Mission Control preferences, no change,
3 & 4) I don't see anything about Spaces in Options 
Thanks for you help

Answer (score 4):

What works for me is:

- go into fullscreen (for example via double-clicking)
- Press control+up
- Drag+drop webex window to desired desktop/display

The window will then have the size it had on the other display, but double-clicking should now enter+exit fullscreen now on the correct display. (Version 41.3.5.8)